# How to set value to existing Textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I've Textbox and Button. I want to show String "Hello World" in Textbox after Clicking the Button. How to do it?

[image: Before Clicking Button]

[image: After Clicking Button]

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: I've not coded yet, I just want to know the way to set value to jsp textbox at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one button onclick of ClickMe button you need to initiate onclick Listener which update the content to text field:

```js
function setFieldValue(){
document.getElementById('firstName').value="Hello World";//this is text set when button clicked
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

First name: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br>
<input type="submit" value="ClickMe" onclick="setFieldValue()">
</body>
</html>
```